# Automatic Deployment: Differences betw. BTS 2016 FP2 and BTS2020

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

in both "what's new" release notes of BTS 2016 Feature Pack 2 and BizTalk 2020, automatic (multi-server) DevOps deployments are announced...

I am wondering if there was any functionality added in BizTalk 2020?

Anyone knows?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[What’s new in BizTalk Server 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/whats-new-in-biztalk-server-2020#new-in-biztalk-server-2020)

- Group Managed Service Accounts
- Blob Adapter
- Audit Log
- New Read Only Operator role

It also includes features from BizTalk 2016 FP3

- Office 365 Adapters

Comment: OK, so if I only want automatic DevOps Deployment, I won't have any benefits switching to 2020 compared to using 2016 FP 3?

Comment: @RobertL. If you are only looking at the deployment aspect, I'm not aware of any differences / benefits.  But with BizTalk 2020 you get another 4 years of lifecycle.  Also with BizTalk 2016 the Feature Packs were Enterprise licence only.  Now the features are available in Standard as well.